# How to merge multiple dynamic arrays and store it in another array using angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular

I am getting multiple arrays dynamically. I need to take **pk_location_id** from those arrays. But the arrays are not merged, so I am facing issue in taking pk_location_id from those arrays.

**I am getting arrays as follows:**

**Array(2)**
0:{pk_location_id: 3, tenant_id: null, locationname: "Karnataka", locationpath: null, location_phone: null, …}
1:{pk_location_id: 4, tenant_id: null, locationname: "Maharashtra", locationpath: null, location_phone: "9876543211", …}

length:2

**Array(3)**
0:{pk_location_id: 5, tenant_id: null, locationname: "banglore", locationpath: null, location_phone: "444444444", …}
1:{pk_location_id: 8, tenant_id: null, locationname: "Mysore", locationpath: "/Karnataka/India/HTL", location_phone: "9888888888", …}
2:{pk_location_id: 9, tenant_id: null, locationname: "Hubli", locationpath: "/Karnataka/India/HTL", location_phone: "876543212", …}

length:3

**Array(1)**
0:{pk_location_id: 6, tenant_id: null, locationname: "jay nagar", locationpath: "/banglore/Karnataka/India/HTL", location_phone: null, …}

length:1

**Array(1)**
0:{pk_location_id: 7, tenant_id: null, locationname: "puna", locationpath: "", location_phone: null, …}

length:1

I tried to merge these arrays using **concat** and **push** but that did not work.

**I tried as follows:**

```
const mergedarray = [].concat(...this.locations);

this.locationIds.push(...this.locations);
```

How to fetch **pk_location_id** from these arrays and store it in to another array?

**I am getting the HTTP response as follows:**

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM5Lb.png)

After getting the response I am filtering it. 
**The code is as follows:**

```
this.locationFilteredList = this.allLocationArray[0].filter(
   (book:Location) => book.parent_location_id === parent_location_id);   
this.locations = this.locationFilteredList;
```

Can anyone please provide solution for this?

Thanks & Regards

Shilpa Kulkarni

Comment: how are you getting these arrays? From a http response?

Comment: Hi @AnuradhaGunasekara  I have edited my question and I have attached my HTTP response also. Can you please check it?

Comment: what is `parent_location_id` ?

Comment: That code is written to display the data in tree view format. In tree view what I am doing is : I have one pk_location_id and have one parent_location_id for that. Based on that parent_location_id it is giving child locations

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a sample idea

```
let arr1 = [{pk_location_id: 3}, {pk_location_id: 2}];
let arr2 = [{pk_location_id: 3}, {pk_location_id: 2}];
let arr3 = [{pk_location_id: 3}, {pk_location_id: 2}];
let combinedArr = [].concat(arr1, arr2, arr3);
for(let locId in combinedArr){
 console.log(locId.pk_location_id);// do whatever you want to do
}
```